# Is there a way to broadcast a message to all (or filtered) WebSocket clients connected to a WebSocket server?

Tags: python, performance, websocket, tornado, broadcast

I am using Python's Tornado WebSocketHandlers to handle websocket connections.

I have some messages that need to be broadcast globally. When I have +1000 clients the following iteration starts to be costly for high-frequency messages:

```
def broadcast(self,msg):
    for client in self.clients:
        client.send(msg)
```

**Is there a way to a perform a sort of a WebSocket multicast using Python and Tornado** (instead of iterating over a list / dict of existing connections) **?**

Comment: I closed this as a dupe since it looks like the other question answers your question ... if it does not let me know ... as an aside you could use something like celery to provide some level of asycronous behaviour